# unknown packaging type aar

Tags: android, maven

I am converting android library project into maven project. I have given packaging type as "aar".

The android-maven-plugin version I am using is 4.1.0.

I am getting error as "unknown packaging type aar"

I am getting the similar error for packaging type 'apklib'

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you show the full pom and the complete message output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AAR) and this [blog](http://lexaux.blogspot.fr/2013/02/building-android-application-with-maven.html), you have to include the android-maven-plugin in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>

    <extensions>true</extensions>         
    <configuration>
        <sign>
            <debug>false</debug>
        </sign>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If it's not recognized, I think you should try to download it manually. Btw, 'apklib' is deprecated, you should always use .aar instead.

Comment: Also note that you have to put this `plugin` tag under `plugins` under `build` tag at the beginning of your `project` tag.